# Breaking down a dollar amount into bill and coin denominations

Tags: c++, integer

I've started coding C++ again after a 6 month break to prepare for a class I'm taking this quarter. I found this idea and thought it would be fun to try and code.

I originally started with input as a string, and wanted to split it into two `int`s at `.`, but this way seemed easier.  Then came the rounding errors. This is why I multiply by such a large number, and 100 was still giving me incorrect values.  I'm really just looking for any feedback on ways I could improve my code, stylistically or otherwise.

```
cout << "Welcome to Dollar Break Down!" << endl; //print welcome message
cout << "Please enter a dollar amount: ";        // prompt for input of a dollar amount

double amt;                                                         // var to store the amount
cin >> amt;                                                         // read in and store amount
cout << endl;                                                       // spacing

int dollars = amt;                                                  // dollars = (int)amt ex: int(45.97) = 45

// compute dollars
dollars / 100 == 1 ?                                                // check if bill amount is single or plural
    cout << dollars / 100 << " hundred" << endl :                   // print singe
    cout << dollars / 100 << " hundreds" << endl;                   // print plural
dollars = dollars % 100;                                            // compute remainder after removing bill amount
dollars / 50 == 1 ?                                         
    cout << dollars / 50 << " fifty" << endl :                      // repeat for each bill type
    cout << dollars / 50 << " fifties" << endl;
dollars = dollars % 50;
dollars / 20 == 1 ?
    cout << dollars / 20 << " twenty" << endl :
    cout << dollars / 20 << " twenties" << endl;
dollars = dollars % 20;
dollars / 10 == 1 ?
    cout << dollars / 10 << " ten" << endl :
    cout << dollars / 10 << " tens" << endl;
dollars = dollars % 10;
dollars / 5 == 1 ?
    cout << dollars / 5 << " five" << endl :
    cout << dollars / 5 << " fives" << endl;
dollars = dollars % 5;
dollars / 1 == 1 ?
    cout << dollars / 1 << " one" << endl: 
    cout << dollars / 1 << " ones" << endl;

cout << endl;                                                   // spacing between dollars and cents

dollars = amt;                                                  // reset dollars to amt for cents calculation
amt *= 10000;                                                   // multiply to remove rounding errors
dollars *= 10000;                                               // same thing
int cents = (amt - dollars) / 100;                              // compute cents without rounding errors

// compute cents
cents / 25 == 1 ?
    cout << cents / 25 << " quarter" << endl :
    cout << cents / 25 << " quarters" << endl;
cents = cents % 25;
cents / 10 == 1 ?
    cout << cents / 10 << " dime" << endl :
    cout << cents / 10 << " dimes" << endl;
cents = cents % 10;
cents / 25 == 1 ?
    cout << cents / 5 << " nickel" << endl :
    cout << cents / 5 << " nickels" << endl;
cents = cents % 5;
cents / 25 == 1 ?
    cout << cents / 1 << " penny" << endl :
    cout << cents / 1 << " pennies" << endl;
```

Comment: Where's `main()`?

Comment: Why are you using `?` here as oposed to `if`?

Comment: Because it looks cleaner (to me) since the format is if one bill then singular, else plural and I preferred the look over if else statements, I did it both ways and liked how this way looked better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stylistically:

- just write `std::` instead of `using namespace std;` (which you didn't show but was implicit)
- use a regular `if()` instead of the ternary operator `?`
- use compound assignment operators like `dollars %= 10;` instead of `dollars = dollars % 10;`
- I'm not a big fan of end-of-line comments, but at the very least, try and put them inside the 80 column mark (most editors will show a marker)

Furthermore, it's a good exercise to make your code more general:

- put the bills `(1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100)` and their strings in a `std::map`, and write your code as a loop over that map. This way you can start to test with only small bills, and then expand to the general problem
- a propos, where are your tests?

Comment: +1 good stuff.  An array is good, but I think a map could work here as well.

Comment: @Jamal good point! Updated.